# Performing multiple API requests on one page using Decodables in Swift 5

Tags: swift, decodable

I'm using `decodable` to get a list of URLS that I need to hit once a `TableView` is loaded.

This is my struct to get the URLS:

```
struct CharactersUrls: Decodable {
    let characters: [String]
}

struct Characters: Decodable {
    let characters: [String]
}

struct CharacterInfo: Decodable {
    let Id: Int
    let name: String
    let status: String
}
```

And here is my func:

```
    fileprivate func getCharactersUrls() {
    let endpoint  = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/\(episodeID ?? "1")"
    guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {
            let charactersUrls = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharactersUrls.self, from: data)
            print("Characters URLS: \(charactersUrls)")

            let endpoints = [charactersUrls]
            print("Endpoints -> \(endpoints)")

        } catch let jsonError {
            print("Error Serializing JSON:", jsonError)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

I'm getting the urls printed in console successfully:

```
Endpoints -> [Rick___Morty.CharactersUrls(characters: ["https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/1", "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/2", "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/38", "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/87",  "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/338"])]
```

Now I need to hit each url to get from it the `id, name, status` and load these in a `tableView`

What is the best approach to do this also by using `Decodable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `CharacterInfo` struct is wrong, `id` is lowercased.

To get the info for all characters you need a second data task. To get notified when all tasks are completed use `DispatchGroup`. For convenience the `status` is decoded as enum.

```
struct CharactersUrls: Decodable {
    let characters: [URL]
}

enum Status : String, Decodable {
    case dead = "Dead", alive = "Alive"
}

struct CharacterInfo: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let status: Status
}

var characterInfos = [CharacterInfo]()

fileprivate func getCharactersUrls() {
    let endpoint  = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/\(episodeID ?? "1")"
    guard let endPointURL = URL(string: endpoint) else { return }

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    let outertask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: endPointURL) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { print(error!); return }

        do {
            let charactersUrls = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharactersUrls.self, from: data)
            print("Characters URLS: \(charactersUrls)")
            for infoURL in charactersUrls.characters {
                group.enter()
                let innertask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: infoURL) { data, response, error in
                    defer{ group.leave() }
                    guard let data = data else { print(error!); return }
                    do {
                        let characterInfo = try JSONDecoder().decode(CharacterInfo.self, from: data)
                        characterInfos.append(characterInfo)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error Getting Info for \(infoURL):", error)
                    }

                }
                innertask.resume()
            }
            group.notify(queue: .main) {
                print(characterInfos)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error Serializing JSON:", error)
        }

    }
    outertask.resume()
}
```

To display the `characterInfos` array in a table view there are zillions of tutorials and examples.